# Tridion Favorites - ability to rename favorite links

Tags: tridion, rename, favorites

I am using Tridion 2011. And I am looking for a way to let users rename the favorite links. Adding a component, folder etc to favorites is straight forward but is there way to let users rename those favorite links?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Out of the box it is not possible to rename the favorite link differently than the original item.

The link is internally maintained by `TCM`, so the name is always shared.

Your best bet would be to develop a GUI extension, that maintains a list of alternative names for the links, but seems like a lot of work for such a small feature.

Comment: The details seem to be in each user's AppData, which has attributes for `Title`, `Icon`, `RefID` (tcm-id), and `Path` (as well as HasChildren and Allow). +1 to Puntero's suggestion--GUI extension if it seems worth it. Just be careful not to interfere with how the CMS manages the existing details (e.g. separate AppData is probably safer than attempting to modify the existing `Title`).

Comment: Thanks guys, this is how we did it.... We created an Extension that stores the renamed titles into a new AppData and then we created a Dataextender to listen to GetListUserFavorites list and replace the title values with the renamed titles stored in the new AppData. But it took lot of research to get the feature done. As part of the extension we intercepted AddUri command to give user an option to rename the favorite with a prompt. We also added a rename option in context menu to modify the already existing favorites by modifying the renamed titles Appdata. In short, yes it is complicated.