# Extending Favorite using DataExtender and how do I debug it?

Tags: debugging, tridion, rename, favorites

I have previously asked a question regarding renaming favorites, here: [Tridion Favorites - ability to rename favorite links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14037820/tridion-favorites-ability-to-rename-favorite-links)

Now based on some research from this question [Can the list of favorites be extended using a Data Extender?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10486726/can-the-list-of-favorites-be-extended-using-a-data-extender)

I am extending the favorites by using dataextender. So the idea is whenever favorite list is retrieved, I would replace it with renamed values of the favorites (the renamed values which are stored as a seperate appdata). But for some reason my dataextender doesnt seem to be working/included in the tridion.

My first question is:
Can I listen to favorites reader by looking for command GetList?

Second Question:
Also in the config, do I just mention it in the ext:DataExtender element or do i need mention other elements like ext:list

Final Question:
Is there a way I can debug my dataextender from visual studio like we can debug event system by attaching to dllhst3g.exe...

Comment: Can't help on the first 2 questions, but I assume you can debug by attaching to IIS (w3wp.exe)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To extend List Favorites, you should listen to GetListUserFavorites command.

No, just ext:dataextender

And yes, as Nuno mentioned, to debug DataExtenders you should attach to w3wp.exe process.

Comment: Thanks a ton, UI Bearcore.... We didnt find this information anywhere on the web... Thanks again!